# How to I make front and back button stick to both sides

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am have trouble on making two buttons to stick to both sides.

Here is the css file

```
#projects h2{
    color:#374054;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#projects{
    background-color:#f9f8fd;
    padding:10px 10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dcd9d9;
    text-align:center;
}

.projects {
    position: relative;
}

.slider {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    -webkit-scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    position: relative;
}


[aria-label="projects"]:focus {
    outline: 4px solid DodgerBlue;
    outline-offset: -3px;
}

[aria-label="projects"] ul {
    display: flex;
}

[aria-label="projects"] li {
    list-style: none;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
    height: 60vh;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
    scroll-snap-stop: always;
}

[aria-label="projects"] figure {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

[aria-label="projects"] img {
    max-height: calc(100% - 2rem);
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

#instructions {
  position: relative;
}

#instructions p {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fefefe;
  background-color: #111;
}

#focus, #hover, #hover-and-focus, #touch {
  display: none;
}

[aria-label="projects"]:hover:focus + #instructions #hover-and-focus {
  display: block;
}

#instructions svg {
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
  fill: #fff;
  vertical-align: -0.5rem;
}

.touch #instructions p {
  display: none !important;
}

.touch #instructions #touch {
  display: block !important;
}

[aria-label="projects controls"] li {
  list-style: none;
}

[aria-label="projects controls"] button {
  /* position:absolute; */
  top: 0;
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #111;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 3rem;
  height: calc(60vh + 4px);
}

#previous {
  left: 0;
}

#next {
  right: 0;
}

button svg {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}
```

here is html file

```
<div id="projects">
        <h2 class="heading">Projects</h2>
        <svg style="display:none">
            <symbol id="arrow-left" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
                <path fill="currentColor" d="m9 4h-4v-2l-4 3 4 3v-2h4z"/>
            </symbol>
            <symbol id="arrow-right" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
                <path fill="currentColor" d="m1 4h4v-2l4 3-4 3v-2h-4z"/>
            </symbol>
        </svg>
        <div class="projects">
            <div class="slider" aria-describedby="instructions" role="region" aria-label="projects">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <figure>
                            <img src="images/1.jpg">
                        </figure>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <figure>
                            <img src="images/2.jpg">
                        </figure>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <figure>
                            <img src="images/3.jpg">
                        </figure>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <figure>
                            <img src="images/4.jpg">
                        </figure>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <figure>
                            <img src="images/5.jpg">
                        </figure>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="instructions">
                <p id="hover-and-focus">
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><use xlink:href="#arrow-left"></use></svg>
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><use xlink:href="#arrow-right"/></svg>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the js file

```
     const projects = document.querySelector('[aria-label="projects"]')
     const slides = projects.querySelectorAll('li')
     const instructions = document.getElementById('instructions')

     const observerSettings = {
       root: projects,
       rootMargin: '-10px'
     }

     if ('IntersectionObserver' in window) {
       const callback = (slides, observer) => {
         Array.prototype.forEach.call(slides, function(entry) {
           entry.target.classList.remove('visible')
           if (!entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
             return
           }
           let img = entry.target.querySelector('img')
           if (img.dataset.src)  {
             img.setAttribute('src', img.dataset.src)
             img.removeAttribute('data-src')
           }
           entry.target.classList.add('visible')
         })
       }

       const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, observerSettings)
       Array.prototype.forEach.call(slides, t => observer.observe(t))

       const controls = document.createElement('ul')
       controls.setAttribute('aria-label', 'projects controls')
       controls.innerHTML = `
       <li>
         <button id="previous" aria-label="previous">
           <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><use xlink:href="#arrow-left"></use></svg>
         </button>
       </li>
       <li>
         <button id="next" aria-label="next">
           <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><use xlink:href="#arrow-right"/></svg>
         </button>
       </li>
       `

       instructions.parentNode.insertBefore(controls, instructions.nextElementSibling)
       instructions.parentNode.style.padding = '0 3rem'

       function scrollIt (slideToShow) {
         let scrollPos = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(slides, slideToShow) * (projects.scrollWidth / slides.length)
         projects.scrollLeft = scrollPos
       }

       function showSlide (dir, slides) {
         let visible = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="projects"] .visible')
         let i = dir === 'previous' ? 0 : 1

         if (visible.length > 1) {
           scrollIt(visible[i])
         } else {
           let newSlide = i === 0 ? visible[0].previousElementSibling : visible[0].nextElementSibling
           if (newSlide) {
             scrollIt(newSlide)
           }
         }
       }

       controls.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
         showSlide(e.target.closest('button').id, slides)
       })

     } else {
       Array.prototype.forEach.call(slides, function (s) {
         let img = s.querySelector('img')
         img.setAttribute('src', img.getAttribute('data-src'))
       })
     }
```

I want to make a slide picture show with control buttons to control left and right. However, both buttons were put right below the image and align at the center with left button at the top and right button at bottom. I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Make a working jsfiddle

Comment: Have you tried `position: absolute`?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried position: absolute. The buttons somehow just were put on the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

you place the buttons inside the slider wrapper the left before the ul of images and right after and you use position absolute

```css
#projects h2{
    color:#374054;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#projects{
    background-color:#f9f8fd;
    padding:10px 10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dcd9d9;
    text-align:center;
}

.projects {
    position: relative;
}

.slider {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    -webkit-scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    position: relative;
}


[aria-label="projects"]:focus {
    outline: 4px solid DodgerBlue;
    outline-offset: -3px;
}

[aria-label="projects"] ul {
    display: flex;
}

[aria-label="projects"] li {
    list-style: none;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
    height: 60vh;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
    scroll-snap-stop: always;
}

[aria-label="projects"] figure {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

[aria-label="projects"] img {
    max-height: calc(100% - 2rem);
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

#instructions {
  position: relative;
}

#instructions p {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fefefe;
  background-color: #111;
}

#focus, #hover, #hover-and-focus, #touch {
  display: none;
}

[aria-label="projects"]:hover:focus + #instructions #hover-and-focus {
  display: block;
}

#instructions svg {
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
  fill: #fff;
  vertical-align: -0.5rem;
}

.touch #instructions p {
  display: none !important;
}

.touch #instructions #touch {
  display: block !important;
}

[aria-label="projects controls"] li {
  list-style: none;
}

[aria-label="projects controls"] button {
  /* position:absolute; */
  top: 0;
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #111;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 3rem;
  height: calc(60vh + 4px);
}

#previous {
position:absolute;
  left: 0;
}

#next {
position:absolute;
  right: 0;
}

button svg {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}
here is html file
```

```html
<div id="projects">
        <h2 class="heading">Projects</h2>
        <svg style="display:none">
            <symbol id="arrow-left" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
                <path fill="currentColor" d="m9 4h-4v-2l-4 3 4 3v-2h4z"/>
            </symbol>
            <symbol id="arrow-right" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
                <path fill="currentColor" d="m1 4h4v-2l4 3-4 3v-2h-4z"/>
            </symbol>
        </svg>
        <div class="projects">
            <div class="slider" aria-describedby="instructions" role="region" aria-label="projects">
             <li>
         <button id="previous" aria-label="previous">
           <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><use xlink:href="#arrow-left"></use></svg>
         </button>
       </li>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <figure>
                            <img src="images/1.jpg">
                        </figure>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <figure>
                            <img src="images/2.jpg">
                        </figure>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <figure>
                            <img src="images/3.jpg">
                        </figure>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <figure>
                            <img src="images/4.jpg">
                        </figure>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <figure>
                            <img src="images/5.jpg">
                        </figure>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                 <li>
         <button id="next" aria-label="next">
           <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><use xlink:href="#arrow-right"/></svg>
         </button>
       </li>
            </div>
            
            <div id="instructions">
                <p id="hover-and-focus">
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><use xlink:href="#arrow-left"></use></svg>
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><use xlink:href="#arrow-right"/></svg>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



      
      
       `
```